# How Can I Revert an Update from an SVN Repository In Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, replace, subversive, revert

I need to revert back to a local dev environment after having replaced it with the contents of an SVN repository?  I'm using Eclipse Luna, SVN, Subversive, Spring MVC.

I would like to revert back to what I originally had as much was deleted from doing an accidental replace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by a "replace" but there are a couple of things you can try to restore the state of your projects.

Firstly, you have SVN revert.  Right-click on the project in the Package Explorer, go to "Team" and then choose "Revert" from the sub-menu.  This will give you the option to restore the state of local files based from Subversion.

If that's not what you're looking for then you've got Eclipse's built-in local history.  Again, if you right-click on the project in Package Explorer then you should see an option to "Restore from local history".  If you select this then you'll be presented with several historical snapshots of the files with which you've been working, so you can hopefully resurrect the desired state of your work from that.

Comment: By replace I mean right clicking, going to replace with, then going to latest from repository. Although your way would work for things in the repository, it will not work for all the things overwritten and deleted with the first replace, ie things not pushed to the repository.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying.  In that case, my second point about the local history _should_ still work because that's independent of your version control system.

Comment: Normally you would be stop on, but when attempting that, I get back a nice 'No deleted resources in the local history for selected container'. Fun times. I am thinking that the local history was overwritten as well.

Comment: Oh dear :-( In that case I'm out of ideas, I'm afraid.

Comment: No worries, I am in the same boat... thank you for responding though.